# Jquery ajax success response every time ended up as undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a text JqTE plugin for rich text editor. However I am facing the problem while filling up text areas  with the big data using ajax call. It seems it is something to do with async calls.

```
function filldata(CusID)
{
         var returningData;
         var data = {   CustomerId: CusID     }     
         data = JSON.stringify(data);
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "Services.svc/GetConditions",
             data: data,

             dataType: "json",
             success: function (result) {
                 var TermsCondition = $($.parseXML(result.GetConditions)).find("Table").find("CommunicationTermsAndConditions").html();
/*TermsCondition will be something like 3000chars.*/
             $("#hdnTerms").val(TermsCondition);
            return true;
                });

}

        var IsAjaxsucces =  filldata(CusID);
        if(IsAjaxsucces){
        --Code that depends on $("#hdnTerms")
        }
```

And I am calling this method in after some time a button click event. But every time I found my hidden field is #hdnTerms is being empty. When I tried in debugger TermsCondition is being filled with the correct data which I am expecting.

I do not want to execute other code until the ajax success completely done so that TermsCondition value will not be empty.

Comment: try to add async: false option in your ajax

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning a value from `filldata()` and then you are surprised that  `filldata()` does not return a value.

First, you should return the value you got from `$ajax()`.

Second, that value will *not* be the return value of your success function.  Ajax returns a “Promise”, which is a structure that someday will give you the desired value.

Like so:

```
function filldata(CusID)
{
  ...
  return  $.ajax({
     ...
  });
}

filldata(CusID).then(function(isAjaxSuccess){
  // Code that depends on $("#hdnTerms")
});
```

Read up on Promises [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Actually i found it now that hidden field is getting filled in google chrome..but not in internet explorer with my code , Even with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
function filldata(CusID)
{
         var returningData;
         var data = {   CustomerId: CusID     }     
         data = JSON.stringify(data);
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "Services.svc/GetConditions",
             data: data
             dataType: "json"}).done(function(result){
                    var TermsCondition = $($.parseXML(result.GetConditions)).find("Table").find("CommunicationTermsAndConditions").html();
                   /*TermsCondition will be something like 3000chars.*/
                    $("#hdnTerms").val(TermsCondition);
                   //You have to validate here
                  --Code that depends on $("#hdnTerms")
                    return true;
                });

}
```

If this is not useful for you, you should use **async:false**